# Probability Question - Picking a Ball

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

There exist Two bags, one has one white ball, other has one black ball. You randomly select a bag and add a white ball in it. You then shake the bag. From the same bag, if you picked a ball and it was white, what is the chance that the other ball in that bag is also white?

I had the following idea: we have 2 cases

1. Balck Ball + White Ball or
2. White ball + White ball

probability of choosing either of the bag = 0.5

probability of picking a white ball = probability of picking from first case or from second = (0.5)(0.5) + (0.5)(1) = 0.75

probability of second ball being white = probability of second white ball in first case or second case = (0.5)(0) + (0.5)(1) = 0.5

so probability that other ball is also white = is 1/2.

Is this approach right?

Comment: Please include your research effort or you'll likely be downvoted by the community.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Thanks Axel and Shaun, I have updated it

Answer (score 1):

$C1:$ You picked The Bag with White ball

Now $P(W)=1$ as there are all white balls in the bag.

$C2:$ You picked The Bag with Black ball

Now $P(W)=0.5$ as there is $1$ Black and $1$ White Ball in the bag.

Hence, $P(C1|W)=\frac{P(C1)P(W|C1)}{P(C1)P(W|C1)+P(C2)P(W|C2)}\Rightarrow P(C1|W)=\frac{(0.5)(1)}{(0.5)(1)+(0.5)(0.5)}=\frac{2}{3}$